# Database inner join QUERY cursor problems SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Table User:
userid, username, password, age, email, gender, height, weight, bmi, bmr

Table Calorie Intake:
userid, (DATE)intakedate, intakeday, calories;

Im trying to Select Calories from table user INNER JOIN table Cal In ON user. uid == Cal.userid, where userid  =? and current date =?

Here is the Query:

```
public CalorieIntake getuserIntake(int id, Date currentdate) {
    CalorieIntake calorieIntake = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    final String UserintQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_CALORIES + " FROM "
            + TABLE_CALORIE_INTAKE + " c " + " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_USERS + " u " +
            "ON" + " c." + KEY_USER_ID + " = u." + KEY_U_ID + " WHERE u." + KEY_U_ID + " =? AND " + KEY_INTAKE_DATE + " =?";
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = db.rawQuery(UserintQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(id), currentdate});

    if (cursor.getCount() < 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        assert cursor != null;
        calorieIntake = new CalorieIntake(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getDate??,
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getDouble(3));


    }
    cursor.close();
    return calorieIntake;
}
```

i put two ?? beside cursor.getDate to highlight it as I cant find a way to retrieve the Type Date.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Store your Date data in Text with this Format -> "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Then use this method:

```
public static Date getDate(Cursor cursor, String colName)
            throws ParseException {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(colName);

        if (!cursor.isNull(idx)) {
            String strDate = cursor.getString(idx);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(strDate);

            return convertedDate;

        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this is great, I have one question. Where do i call the method? in the if statement?

Comment: @johnsmith why (-1). is not it your answer?

Comment: @johnsmith please select it as answer